Branch to context mapping in CircleCI
We have somewhat complex pipeline for building mobile apps for multiple white-labeled clients.
Currently we have a lot of steps inside mobile workflow to build different clients and different envs which is not scalable as client base grows. I am aware of matrix feature for this solution, but we have different triggers based on the branch.
Is there a way to mitigate this by using some kind of mappings between branch CI is running on and context which holds vars for each of them?
Does anyone have any better solution in mind?
Ideally solution would be based on matrix + mappings where based on branch job would be run with correct context, which could be array of context to build multiple apps in the same run.
